# How to restore app folder in a symfony 3 project?

Tags: php, phpstorm, symfony

my app folder was deleted without my intention, is there any way to restore it, i have all my routing and Roles configuration in it
i'm using Php storm if this has any relation with my problem

Comment: Using a source management tool per-chance?

Comment: Done a backup recently per-chance?

Comment: Maybe you used git?

Comment: Like to mention the OS you are using per-chance?

Comment: using windows 10, developping with php storm even my back-up zipped folder doesn't even containt this app folder ...

Comment: i didn't use git :/

Comment: Have you copied the sites to a UAT/LIVE server yet? You could get code back from there if yuo have

Comment: i only keeped a zipped folder for back-up and i found the same problem 
so the problem is with the original copy, php storm is supposed to have a real time saving proccess but in my case it deleted my app folder
Ps: this problem occured with another member of my group and he couldn't resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Project view, right click on the root directory of your project, Local History -> Show History. If you're lucky, the folder with all its contents will be there. If you're not, have fun restoring everything manually.
2. Start using a version control system, for crying out loud.